# Semantic UI modal on href

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic-UI Modal with an href link.  Using with button attached-events works. However, I'm doing something wrong as when using with  href link, it does not work.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.imgclick.modal')
       .modal('attach events', '.test.a', 'show')
      ;
     });   </script>
```

and my test modal

```
 <div class="ui linkmodal imgclick modal">
 <div class="header">Header</div>
 </div>
```

and my trigger

```
  <a href="#" class="test">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.modal('attach events', '.test.a', 'show')` is where its wrong

Shouldnt it be `a.test`?

And `$('.imgclick.modal')` doesnt match any dom specified in you html snippet

You need to add imgclick class
`<div class="ui linkmodal modal imgclick">`

Comment: My code was incorrect, I copied and pasted the wrong snippet with the dom for 'imgclick'. That was always there.

Comment: About the '.test.a' semantic-ui modal button example has '.test.button'